# How I can resolve bug with log in more than once?

Tags: android, singleton

I am building an app where user have to log in.

But the problem is when user clicks on log in button sometimes he must wait response from server (that period is maybe 3,4 or 5 seconds) and, while he is waiting **if he clicks once more** on log in button, then when data from server come, he will be logged in application **twice**.

Could I resolve that problem with Singleton or maybe there is some other solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show a loading , or disable clicking till the data has been fetched

Answer (score 1):

You can simply disable the login button after the user clicked it(while he waits for a server response).

Answer (score 1):

You can use request manager to control/cancel request.
RequestManager.getInstance(getActivity()).cancelAll(REQUEST_TAG);

This will cancel all old request & will give result of the latest one only.

Answer (score 0):

I usually disable the button when user click and then when the button finish the action enable the button.

Example:

```
Button signin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
signin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
           signin.setClickable(false);

           //make your logic

           signin.setClickable(true);
    }
});
```

if you call an Asyncktask inside the button, you can enable the button in the `onPostExecute()`